# Error reading csv as a zoo object - certain lines with 'bad entries'

Tags: r, zoo

I'm working on a time series of weather data (available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhbznsn37lgoots/OakParkR.csv?dl=0)) and trying to convert it to a zoo object so I can use a package which works on zoo objects ('Evapotranspiration').

The code I'm using is:

```
require(zoo)
x = read.zoo(file = "OakParkR.csv", format = "%d-%b-%y", tz = "", index.column = 1)
```

The error I'm getting states:

```
index has bad entries at data rows: 1 36 166 167 214 265 272 276 279 288 290 
292 299 305 308 321 323 328 332 341 344 354 359 372 376 384 392 590 592 676
924 925 1666 1667 1668 1669 2420 2421 2422 2424 2426 2427 2441 2442 2443 2444 2794
```

From looking at other problems and solutions - I think the date is in the correct format as only certain rows are being highlighted as 'bad entries', not all of them. I can't see other problems other than the date being in the wrong format.

I don't understand why there are only errors on some rows and not others, maybe someone has seen this issue before?

Comment: You need to skip the first line, as it contains header. And also you need to say to `read.zoo` how missing values are coded.

Comment: Thanks I adapted the code which is now this: x = read.zoo(file = "OakParkR.csv", header = T, format = "%d-%b-%y", tz = "", index.column = 1, na.strings =" ") but I still get an error for each row except row 1. I've also tried na.strings = "" and na.strings = "\t"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `csv` has empty values. You can fill with NAs and then turn into a `zoo` object. You could try this:

```
x<- read.csv("OakParkR.csv", header=TRUE)
na.fill(x,NA)
x<- zoo(x)
x[33:35]
#date      imax Tmax imin Tmin  irain rain cbl    wdsp ihm hm iddhm ddhm ihg hg soil  
#33 02-Feb-07 0     9.1 0     -1.7 0      0.1 1026.2  3.9 0   10 0     340  0   14  5.970
#34 03-Feb-07 0     9.2 0     -3.0 0      0.0 <NA>    2.4 0    7 0     130  0   11  3.101
#35 04-Feb-07 0     7.7 0     -3.7 0      0.0 1031.8  3.3 0    8 0     330  0   12  2.668
```

Comment: The `na.fill` line has no effect and the result of the above is a zoo object representing a "character" matrix in which the first column is the date in "character".  The index will be 1, 2, 3, ...   This is unlikely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","` and also omit `tz=""` (unless `"POSIXct"` datetimes are really desired -- but since the input has no times `"Date"` class, which is what we get if we omit `tz=""`, seems more appropriate here).

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo("OakParkR.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", format = "%d-%b-%y")
```